# pass an array from Pro*c to Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, proc

We have a user-defined datatype in Oracle which is used in a procedure as an input argument. We are trying to call this procedure from Pro*C.
In Oracle, the user-defined data type is VARRAY(21) of VARCHAR2(500).

In Pro*C we tried similar to the sample program 9 in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/a97269/pc_07pls.htm#i2344

On compiling we are getting the error "Wrong number or types of arguments in call". [Pro*C code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGCVY.png)

Any help on how to pass an array to a procedure is appreciated.

Comment: Don't add a screenshot to your question when you can put the code properly formated

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that this declaration is happening into an `EXEC SQL EXECUTE` block, while you're doing it into a `DECLARE SECTION`.
Do the declaration and assignment like this:

```
EXEC SQL EXECUTE
DECLARE
/* your declaration here*/
BEGIN 
/* call to the procedure here*/
END; 
END-EXEC;
```